# How can I remove the white space after transforming an element?

Tags: html, css, transform

I am facing an issue. I checked a lot of other StackOverflow threads, but none worked for my scenario.
So, basically, I have two `div`s, one transformed on top of another by a specified value.
But, there is a lot of white space between the transformed `div` and the `h1` text which I want to remove.

Here is my code:

```css
.div1,
.div2 {
  height: 200px;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 200px
}

.div2 {
  width: 190px;
  transform: translateY(-20%);
  background-color: purple;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

I have attached an image of the whitespace for better understanding:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/50uAi.png

Any solutions would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Please read [ask], where it says "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope, this can help just add **margin-top** in minus then you can adjust alignment proper  in whitespace

```css
.div1, .div2 {
  height: 200px;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 200px
}

.div2 {
  width: 190px;
  transform: translateY(-20%);
  background-color: purple;
  z-index: 10;
}

h1 {
    margin: -32px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the white space comes from the margin around your title, you can use this css code to remove it:

```
h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

You can also add a negative margin to the bottom of the second box, which you can get by calculating `20%` of the box height (see [this post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) for an explanation of css variables.

```css
:root {
  --box-height: 200px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.div1,
.div2 {
  height: var(--box-height);
}

.div1 {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: var(--box-height);
}

.div2 {
  width: calc(var(--box-height) - 10px);
  transform: translateY(-20%);
  margin-bottom: calc(-0.2 * var(--box-height));
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the margin css property will change the space between elements the padding is the the space between an elements border but has a similar effect.

```
h1{
/*      top right bottom Left  */
margin: -15px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: -15px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```